# SUMMARIZECOLUMNS with CALCULATE and FILTER returning blank fields

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to summarize a table parking transaction records across several facilities and two sources, meter and app payment.  This table is called AllTransactions and has the following fields:

| Zone | Parking Start Date | Parking End Date | Duration | Parking Amount | Source | Year | Quarter | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Text | Datetime | Datetime | Time | Number | Text | Number | Number | Number |

I'm trying to summarize this with a total revenue column for each zone by month, as well as columns for app and meter revenue, but my filtered revenue column expression is returning blank fields.

I am using the following table formula to create my summary:

```
Summary = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    AllTransactions[Year],
    AllTransactions[Month],
    AllTransactions[Zone],
    "Total Hourly Revenue",
    SUM(AllTransactions[ParkingAmount]),
    "Meter Revenue",
    CALCULATE(
        Sum(AllTransactions[ParkingAmount]),
        FILTER(AllTransactions, AllTransactions[Source] = "Meter")
    )
)
```

And yet, the fields in the "Meter Revenue" column come back blank (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLqjQ.png)) while I need them to give the total of the ParkingAmount field for every row in that zone, month and year where the source is "Meter".  It seems like the issue is with my use of the CALCULATE or FILTER expressions - could anyone identify the problem or suggest a better way?  Thanks.

Comment: Your DAX code seems to be correct!